# Can I use a Python list in a for loop'ed SQL query?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I intend to loop through a list(or dictionary, other data type if appropriate) passing each element as parameter to a query to reduce the read time on a database for each item (<1500) I want to pass as a parameter to the query.

I cannot resolve the illegal variable name/number issue out of cx_Oracle.  I've tried several different data types and even sanitized down to a string (in comments below) inside the for loop, but each returns the same error to me.

Is there a way to do this without using the IN sql operator (which is limited to 1000 parameters on my DB version)?   Am I missing a module that does something like this more effectively?

The below code results in the following error:

> ```
> cur2.execute(SQL2, param)
> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
> ```

This is the pseudo code of what I'm working on:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cx_Oracle

ip = 'my.ip'
port = 1521
SID = 'ORADB'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)

conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect('un','pw', dsn_tns)
conn2 = cx_Oracle.connect('un2/pw2@other/target')

SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT PARAM FROM TABLE"

if conn1:
    cur = conn1.cursor()
    cur.execute(SQL)
    res = cur.fetchall()

 if conn2:

    SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM LARGE_TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%:paramstr%'"

    realparamlist = list(res)
    cur2 = conn2.cursor()
    for param in realparamlist:
       #eqpstr=str(param)
       #eqpstr=eqpstr.strip('(').strip(')').strip(',').strip('\'')

       #cur2.execute(SQL2, eqpstr)
       cur2.execute(SQL2, param)
       res2 = cur2.fetchall()
       print res2

#todo other things with res2 and res

cur.close()
cur2.close()
conn1.close()
conn2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this instead:

```
SQL2 = "SELECT * FROM LARGE_TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%' || :paramstr || '%'"
```

Note that the bind variable name cannot be found inside quotes. Oracle will treat that as a string, not as a bind variable!

Second, your list of parameters will be a list of one-tuples, which isn't what you want. Instead you should do something like this, which will unpack those one-tuples into a simple list of values:

```
realparamlist = [p for p, in res]
```

Finally, in the second cursor execute you will need something like this instead:

```
cur2.execute(SQL2, paramstr = param)
```

Hope that gets you going!